# Independence of two constant random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables taking a value $a$ with probability $1$. Is it true that $X$ ad $Y$ are independent?
This seems to be true since
$$P(X \in A, Y \in B)  = \begin{cases}
1\cdot 0 = P(X \in A)P( Y \in B) \ ; \ a \in A, \ a \notin B, \\
1\cdot 1 \ ; \ a \in A, \ a \in B, \\
0\cdot 1 \ ; \  a \notin A, \ a \in B, \\
0\cdot 0 \ ; \  a \notin A, \ a \notin B. 
\end{cases}
$$
But intuitively $X$ and $Y$ are the same; shouldn't they be dependent? Also we say if $Y = X$, then $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Comment: If we say $Y=X$, then $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. No it doesn't, as this example shows!

Comment: Maybe it is helpful to think about independence as "if I know the outcome of $X$, it doesn't give me *more* information about $Y$." When $X$ and $Y$ are constant, you already know all the information about $Y$, so knowing the outcome of $X$ doesn't give you more information about $Y$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Missed it! So can we conclude  `X=Y` and `X` and `Y` are independent, iff they are constants with probability `1`? Since Var(`X+X`) = 2Var(`X`), thus, Var(`X`) = 0.